# Rescaling quiver arrows in physical units consistent to the aspect ratio of the axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector

I've been spending the past couple of hours trying to customize `matplotlib.quiver` without much luck. The documentation is quite confusing and I haven't been able to parse out how to set each parameter. In my axes, one vertical pixel is much less physical distance than one horizontal pixel, and I want quiver to autoscale the arrows to this aspect ratio. What I'm currently getting are horizontal arrows with the following code:

```
Tlevs = np.arange(-1.,8.5,.5) + 0.
yy, zz = np.meshgrid(ds.YC, ds.Z)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
fig.set_tight_layout(True)
im = ax.contourf(T_clim.YC, T_clim.Z, T_clim, levels=Tlevs)
ax.quiver(yy[::3,::10], zz[::3,::10], 
          vpFep_b[::3,::10], wpFep_b[::3,::10], 
          pivot='mid', angles='xy', units='xy')
ax.set_xlabel('Y [m]', fontsize=13)
ax.set_ylabel('Depth [m]', fontsize=13)
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
cbar.set_label(r"[$^\circ$C]")
```

[image: Contour plot with quiver overlaying it]

Setting the quiver options to the following only gives dots for what the arrows should be:

```
ax.quiver(yy[::3,::10], zz[::3,::10], 
              vpFep_b[::3,::10], wpFep_b[::3,::10], 
              pivot='mid', angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scales=1.)
```

[image]

and:

```
ax.quiver(yy[::3,::10], zz[::3,::10], 
              vpFep_b[::3,::10], wpFep_b[::3,::10], 
              pivot='mid', angles='xy', scale_units='xy')
```

gives the following error:

```
/home/takaya/miniconda3/envs/uptodate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/quiver.py:666: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  length = a * (widthu_per_lenu / (self.scale * self.width))
/home/takaya/miniconda3/envs/uptodate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/quiver.py:666: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  length = a * (widthu_per_lenu / (self.scale * self.width))
/home/takaya/miniconda3/envs/uptodate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/quiver.py:719: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  short = np.repeat(length < minsh, 8, axis=1)
/home/takaya/miniconda3/envs/uptodate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/quiver.py:733: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  tooshort = length < self.minlength
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to plot the arrows in the same units and scale as the axis? I don't understand what the desired output is

Comment: Yes, the same scale as the actual physical units of the axes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [`quiver` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html) says:

> To plot vectors in the x-y plane, with u and v having the same units as x and y, use `angles='xy'`, `scale_units='xy'`, `scale=1`

Thus, using this arguments your problem will be solved. That is because the keyword `units` affects the arrow dimensions **except for length**, and `scale_units` affects **only** the lenght.

### Edit:

### Examples of parameter behaviour of matplotlib's quiver

It is true that the documentation is not completely clear, and there are many parameters with similar names which in addition to that, are unique to quiver.

Below there are many examples of the behaviour of different parameters, in particular the ones of interest to this question: `angles`, `units` and `scale_units`. Each example has an image that can be expanded by clicking on it.

The data for all the plots is the same, and can be reproduced using this code:

```
x = np.linspace(0,50,5)
y = np.linspace(-150,150,7)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
U = 3.5*np.ones_like(X)
V = 3.5*np.ones_like(Y)
```

#### `angles`

The entry in the documenatation is:

> angles : [ ‘uv’ | ‘xy’ ], array, optional
>
> Method for determining the angle of the arrows. Default is ‘uv’.
>
> ‘uv’: the arrow axis aspect ratio is 1 so that if U*==*V the orientation of the arrow on the plot is 45 degrees counter-clockwise from the horizontal axis (positive to the right).
>
> ‘xy’: arrows point from (x,y) to (x+u, y+v). Use this for plotting a gradient field, for example.

In our case, the ratio between U and V is one, therefore the arrows will point in 45 degrees in the 'uv' case, however, in the 'xy' case, as the range of the y and x axis is different, the arrows won't point in 45 degrees in order to preserve the displacement from (x,y) to (x+u, y+v). This is important to take into account, since depending on the axis aspect ratio, a gradient (u,v)=(1,1) won't have a 45 degrees angle.

[image: angles]

#### `units`

The entry of the documentation is:

> units : [ ‘width’ | ‘height’ | ‘dots’ | ‘inches’ | ‘x’ | ‘y’ | ‘xy’ ]
>
> The arrow dimensions (except for length) are measured in multiples of this unit.
>
> ‘width’ or ‘height’: the width or height of the axis
>
> ‘dots’ or ‘inches’: pixels or inches, based on the figure dpi
>
> ‘x’, ‘y’, or ‘xy’: respectively X, Y, or in data units
>
> The arrows scale differently depending on the units. For ‘x’ or ‘y’, the arrows get larger as one zooms in; for other units, the arrow size is independent of the zoom state. For ‘width or ‘height’, the arrow size increases with the width and height of the axes, respectively, when the window is resized; for ‘dots’ or ‘inches’, resizing does not change the arrows.

As explained above, this parameters defines the units in which all dimensions except the length of the arrow are measured. However, the parameter width (which is the most rellevant since the arrow headwidth and headlength and so on are defined as multiples of it) has a default values which depends on what units are used.

Below there is an example of different units, fixing the width to comparable cases. The parameter dots or inches is nearly equivalent, and therefore only one of them is considered in the example. Thus, width is set to 0.01 for 'width' and 'height', 3 for 'dots' and 2 for 'x','y' and 'xy'. Not fixing the same width yields different result depending on the backend: i.e. with [matplotlib inline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvvIZ.png) in jupyter there is no difference in any case and with [Qt5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5In58.png) there are some, but its hard to interpret as the width is unknown.

[image: units]

It can be seen that as the plot axes are wider than taller, setting units to 'width' yields thicker arrows compared to 'length', because the width is the same. The same goes when comparing 'x', 'y' and 'xy', a distance of 1 measured according to the x axis is much larger than a distance of 1 according to the y axis.

#### `scale_units`

The entry in the documentation is:

> scale_units : [ ‘width’ | ‘height’ | ‘dots’ | ‘inches’ | ‘x’ | ‘y’ | ‘xy’ ], None, optional
>
> If the scale kwarg is None, the arrow length unit. Default is None.
>
> e.g. scale_units is ‘inches’, scale is 2.0, and (u,v) = (1,0), then the vector will be 0.5 inches long.
>
> If scale_units is ‘width’/’height’, then the vector will be half the width/height of the axes.
>
> If scale_units is ‘x’ then the vector will be 0.5 x-axis units. To plot vectors in the x-y plane, with u and v having the same units as x and y, use angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1.

The explanation about scaling when resizing the plot is the same as in units. However, the "If the scale kwarg is None" statment is completely unclear and leads to error.

If scale is None, then the lenght of the arrows will be set to a default value depending on scale_units in order to keep a reasonable ratio between width and height and to keep the arrows in good shape (i.e. a reasonable head). Then, scale_units won't be propperly appreciated until the plot is resized (due to the differences in scaling depending on scale_units).

If scale is different than None, then the arrow lenght is not set to its default anymore, it follows the examples in the documentation.

Below there is a plot comparing different values of scale_units, with scale=1 and units set to its default value 'width'.

[image: scale_units]

It can be seen that the 'y' case, makes the arros look like dots, due to the difference in size between the U,V vectors which is around 5 and the y scale which goes between -150 and 150, whereas in the case of 'width' and 'lenght', 5 times the size of the plot axes makes the arrows huge.

Comment: I added more details to my question above but I don't think the options are worked how I quite want them to. The size of the arrows don't seem to change for whatever `scales` I give.

Comment: Can you post the data (preferably a minimal example that shows the same problem) used to generate the plot? If they are dots maybe the arrows are really small (the order of the y scale is 1e6, thus, arrows of meter scale will look like plots)

Comment: I uploaded the data here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/id4moyv6pbnxdaw/AABOgy48Qe1EIuxKcfLX2lJta?dl=0

Comment: `vFe` is the x component and `wFe` is the y component of the vector for the quiver plot. The physical axes for the variables of vFe and wFe are `y` and `z`.

Comment: Could you post it in csv format? Or simply copy a 3x3 or 4x4 piece of the matrix? I have never used `.nc` files and I don't plan on learning only for this.

Comment: I uploaded the `.cvs` format for `vFe` and `wFe` individually here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f3u7gblu0n3m40x/AAA-xzmRJqxi4YBlamAlZNO3a?dl=0
The first column corresponds to the depth (`z` axis) of each row and the header is the distance along the `y` axis for each column.

Comment: @roxyboy I have looked at `wFe`, whose mean is 1e-10 and the sum of all 8000 values is around 1e-6. `vFe` has a mean around 1-8. It is impossible to see arrows that size in the same units as the y,z axis. You will have to play with the `scale` parameter to be able to see the arrows